# Firewire 800 with Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewire

I have two windows machine with windows server 2003 installed on them. 
I am running a Lab View script on 1 machine and storing the data. But since it has less memory, I want to transfer data to another machine using firewire 800.
Is it possible to configure out the second machine just as an external HDD attached to it and write data directly to it?
(This is possible with MACs)
Dont want to use the ethernet (internet/ TCP/IP prot.) to transfer the data.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason why ethernet is not an option? With gigabit, it'll run faster than firewire 800.

Comment: @Darth: Well, for the purpose of the question it should be irrelevant *why* they don't want to use Ethernet. The question explicitly asks how to do it with FireWire instead of generally asking how to transfer files ... If I'm asking how to solve a problem with technology A I'd be pretty annoyed if everyone first answers how to solve it with technology B – in many cases such answers would warrant a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything which replicates Target Disk Mode with windows; however, you can get IP over firewire by connecting the two systems with a firewire cable and [setting up the connections](http://lifehacker.com/105906/transfering-files-between-two-computers-on-your-network-fast). This is IP over Firewire and not IP over ethernet, so hopefully it meets your needs.